# Retrieve Data from Database by Passing an ID, c++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from my database giving it only an ID number. My database has 2 columns, first is ID, and second is an image path.
so if i pass ID=3, it should return the path corresponding to that ID.

I have tried to do that, but I am stuck at query.

```
mysql_query (conn, "SELECT * FROM table" );
res = mysql_use_result(conn);
row = mysql_fetch_row(res)
ID = atoi(row[0]);
path = row[1];
printf("ID: %i", ID);

printf("Image Path: %s", path);
```

Please help:)

Comment: why not select from the table with a `WHERE` clause instead. Is it necessary to select all before getting specific data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is not really clear. First case, for each row you want to display id/path:

```
mysql_query (conn, "SELECT * FROM table" );
res = mysql_use_result(conn);
while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) {
  ID = atoi(row[0]);
  path = row[1];
  printf("ID: %i", ID);
  printf("Image Path: %s", path);
}
```

Other possibility, you want only one row because you know the ID you are looking for. Then you can decide to retrieve only the missing column with something like:

```
mysql_query (conn, "SELECT path FROM table WHERE id=ID" );
```

In some more complicated cases, lets say even if with the WHERE you may have multiple rows, you can keep only the first one for example by adding the TOP condition in your query. In any cases you need to think on what will be returned for real.

I didn't test the code I wrote, just edited a bit what you posted (just to be fair ^^)

Comment: How would you really parameterise the `where` clause? The current version isn't going to do anything useful.

Comment: If you have a realistic case I can take a look, but the original question was a bit messy. I used ID as previously defined variable compared to id which is the column name, I don't know if I'm answering your question...

Comment: All I meant was that as-is the `where` clause wouldn't do anything, and a complete answer would indicate how to actually filter from some variable. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a few problems with basic computer concepts. For instance, the concept of having one thing versus more things. You fetch *one* row, but your database table has multiple rows and your query returns all rows. (No `WHERE` clause).

The obvious solution is to either fetch all rows, or (better) restrict your query to just the row you want.